# Show different viewType in RecyclerView based on information in database?

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, android-cursor

Hit a bit of a roadblock and wondering how to solve it, seems like the chicken and the egg to me, could do with a fresh pair of eyes.

I have a database with information on places in them. I want to show all the places ordered by distance in my `RecyclerView`.

I've actually accomplished this already when there's only one `viewType`. However this is what I can't figure out, I have want to show a different view for places that are within a certain distance to the user. So within 100meters for example.

That information is within my database, so when `getItemViewType(int position)` is called on setAdapter() my `CursorLoader` hasn't finished pulling out all the information so I get a null pointer exception.

To my question:

Is there a way for me to wait for my `CursorLoader` to finish then work with my adapter and not have a null `Cursor`? When I try to call `.setAdapter()` after the loader has finished I get the following in my logs: `No adapter attached; skipping layout` because a `RecyclerView` needs the adapter to be set when the activity is created.

My `getItemViewType(position)` currently looks like this:

```
if (!cursor.isClosed()) {
    cursor.moveToPosition(position);
}
if (cursor.getInt(2) <= 100) {
   return TYPE_NEARBY;
} else {
  return TYPE_NOT_NEARBY;
}
```

Essentially I need to use the data in my `CursorLoader` to determine the `viewType` and load a different view for that cell. With one ViewType it works because I don't need to check the distance, they're all the same view.

Thanks for any help you can offer!

Comment: `getItemViewType` shouldn't be called if `getItemCount` returns `0`, which should be the case if your cursor is null.

Comment: Just ran it with breakpoints and you're right. i got it working by updating the ids on my onBindViewHolder when it gets called. move cursor to position and check again to update my viewholder.  I think it's because i'm using a holderId in my viewholder which needed to be updated as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got this working in the end thanks to blackbelts comment.

Ran through the process in debug mode and everything works as expected. I just had to ensure that I was doing the right things with the data in my `onBindViewHolder(int position)`.

The main issue was because I had a "holderId" int in my ViewHolder that was different to my viewType int so I probably just confused them.